# Problem with generating association inside dbml file for LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I have created a dbml file in my project, and then dragged two tables from a database into the designer. This is the tables for order header and order lines, and order lines have a foreign key to order header to make it a one to many relationship.

As soon as the two tables are dragged onto the designer, the association arrow appear and everything looks correctly. In the properties for the association, Child Property is set to True, Access is public, Inheritance mode is (none), Name is OrderLines (originally taOrderLines, but edited by me to be called OrderLines.

The problem is that no OrderLines property is created. I checked manually in the generated cs file also, and neither the word OrderLines or Association is found there.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I had this problem twice now and somehow I wasn't able to find this question when looking for a solution (at least not at first). The question text itself is fine, but the question name somewhat broad making it hard to figure that this is the right question. As a result I ended up finding the question only while trying to write my own (I guess the text based search did it's job well). The unasked question that I wrote was titled something like "Associated table is not accessible from model".

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Make sure each class has a primary key.

---

If your objects don't have a Primary Key property in the dbml, LinqToSql object tracking can't see those objects and relational properties will not be generated.

Comment: That was actually the problem. I did not even consider that the database I was working against did not have proper primary keys set up. The OrderLines table had no primary key. When the primary key got created, it worked as expected.